# I want to show status without refreshing page

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs5

```
                {
                    text: 'SFTP Upload Status',
                    width: 115,
                    align: 'center',
                    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                    sortable: false,
                    items: [
                        {
                            getClass: function (v, meta, record) {
                                var cls = '';

                                if (record.get('sftpStatus') === 'Success') {
                                    cls = 'x-fa fa-check text-green';
                                } else if (record.get('sftpStatus') === 'Processing') {
                                    cls = 'x-fa fa-spinner fa-spin'
                                } else  if (record.get('sftpStatus') === 'Failed') {
                                    cls = 'x-fa fa-close text-red';
                                }

                                return cls;
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

I want to show the status without refreshing page , currently I'm refreshing page to show this status

Comment: You need to refresh the store of the grid.

Comment: I am afraid even if the data is refreshed the action column will not change it's style class. You need to use the `reconfigure` function of the grid and re-create all the columns. Alternatively, you can use a `widget column` which can re-render it's content and style according to current data.